# Rebuilding Unity Project from DLLs?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine

I have lost my Unity project which was located on my hard drive. Fortunately, I have found some files that were associated with my project. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plFdM.png).

Now, I have successfully converted `Assembly-CSharp.dll` into equivalent C# with a .NET Reflector but I can't find a way to rebuild my Unity project... (or at least a good part of it) How can I do this? Logically, the files that I have now are all we need to recreate the project.

Thank you for your help.

Please comment below if you wish the files to be uploaded.

My original Unity project (which I worked on for a few months) does transitions between menus, by touching, swiping, flicking, or pressing arrow buttons.

.NET Reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Comment: Haven't you already tried asking this about 20 times on here AND on gamedev?

I'm really sorry to say this, but the bottom-line is, no, that's not all you need to rebuild the project. You need all the project-settings too, which you cannot find from the build.

As I mentioned on an earlier SO post from you (which I think you literally copy-pasted here), your best option is to use version-control next time. All the best!

Comment: @andeart I am really desperate for a solution because I've worked too hard on this project... :(

Comment: Why don't you try re-creating it? You have the scripts (equivalents) which is a considerable half of the work, if not more.

Comment: @andeart Thank you for the reply. I forgot which scripts where attached to each GameObject, and the entire structure of the Hierarchy. (I finished the project 3 months ago) Do you think uploading my files would help? I don't mind sharing them.

Comment: No, I don't think anyone would be able to help better than you can yourself. It's a matter of re-creating the scene hierarchy and structure then. Good luck!

Comment: I think this question is unsuitable for Bounty. The +100 is likely to be for a solution while there is none. While there is no solution, there is a way to prevent this from happening, using Version Control.

Comment: Some beginners or fresh developers might not know about management tool / codes versioning tool. Please use them starting from today. E.g bitbucket.org. Store all your projects in remote server controlled by versioning everytime you've implemented some important works / features. You can simply revert the codes back to previous commit if the latest one is corrupted / bug occurs.

Answer (score 7):

You can recover **all your scripts** if you have the Assembly DLL, but nothing more. All the scenes, images, fonts, models, etc... are gone.

If anything, you can **try decompiling the assets files** and maybe you can recover some of those. For that you'll need special decompiling tools, such as [disunity](https://github.com/ata4/disunity).

It's an experimental tool and has not been updated a lot since Unity 5 came out, but you can give it a try and maybe recover some files from your project.

Good luck with it !

Answer (score 5):

The answer: NO. You simply cannot do this.

Unfortunately, I know this from experience. I ended up having my programming team hard-code values and have scripts programmatically attached to game objects in case the project was corrupted, so I COULD simply drag the scripts back into a new project and be half way there. It's a hard lesson learned.